# Why are duplicate events being logged in Branch.io when using Branch SDK in Flutter for custom events in Android?

Tags: android, flutter, duplicates, branch.io, custom-events

We are using Branch.io sdk (ver 5.1.0) in our flutter application, we are triggering certain custom events. But some events are getting logged twice(duplicate events), even when they are triggered only once in the code. The number of duplicate events is low and is not consistent. We have noticed this in Android OS. Is this a known issue? If yes, then is there a resolution? If no, can someone point us in a direction that might be causing this issue?

Debugged the code and found the events were only placed once in the code and hence should only be triggered once. We were expecting if an event is triggered once it should only be logged once. It is not a consistent bug even. Only sometimes, duplicate events are logged.